# Anotação Google Charts fora da coluna

Tags: google-charts, annotation

Ao criar o gráfico, com annotations para a column, por conta do 'stem', mesmo definindo sua cor como 'transparent', o mesmo continua lá, ocupando espaço, como fazer para colocar uma anotação dentro da coluna usando o style: line.

Já tentei de várias formas sem sucesso quem puder me ajudar, fico muito agradecido. 
Abs.

Segue código abaixo:

```
<div id="grafico_vendas_produtos_valor"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('grafico_vendas_produtos_valor');

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Data', {label: 'Produtos (Un.)', type: 'number'} , {label: 'Valor (R$)', type: 'number'} ],

    ['01/08/2019', 2000, 1000 ],
    ['02/08/2019', 2000, 1000 ],
    ['03/08/2019', 2000, 1000 ],

  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: ' ' });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ',',groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: ''});
  formatter.format(data, 2);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
              { calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation" }, 2,

                { calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 2,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation" },

              ]);

  var classicOptions = {
    height: 400,
    chartArea: { 'width': '90%', 'height': '75%', 'top': '10%' },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    legend: {position: 'top'},
    annotations: {
      style: 'line',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 11,
      },
      stem:{
        color: 'transparent',
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      ignoreBounds: 'true',
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 45,
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
      },
    },
    vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent'
        }
    },
    series: {
      0: { targetAxisIndex: 0, color: '#1976D2' },
      1: { targetAxisIndex: 1, color: '#61C784' },
    },
    vAxes: {
      // Adds titles to each axis.
      0: {
          format: ' ',
          minValue: 0,
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
          },
      },
      1: {
          format: ' ',
          minValue: 0,
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
          },
      }
    }
  };

  function drawClassicChart() {
    var classicChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
    classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
    classicChart.draw(view, classicOptions);
  }

  drawClassicChart();
};
```

segue imagem do grafico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Ezequiel, coloque o código que você está tentando alterar, assim as pessoas conseguem te ajudar da melhor forma. Seja bem vindo à comunidade!

Comment: esclareci melhor e acrescentei uma imagem do gráfico que tenho, no exemplo acrescentei valores menores do que na imagem, muito obrigado Bruno.

Comment: Bom, eu executei seu código aqui e não entendi muito bem em qual resultado você quer chegar.

Comment: o stem está atrapalhando a posição do annotation, o stem esta definido como transparent, se for definido como black, por exemplo, da pra visualizá-lo, o que eu queria é colocar a anotação na vertical e dentro da coluna

Comment: Você já tentou setar o ignoreBounds para false? Vê se resolve seu problema.

Comment: Testei, mas não funcionou